# Trying to target specific menu items to change only the first four items in my menu's css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I have been working on this code to change the css of only the first four items in my list and I know the easiest way to do this would be through classes but I didn't create the site and whoever did used aspx to generate the menu.

In the CSS there is code to set the menu to expand to the right

```
ul.menu ul ul { margin:0 0 0 10px; left:12em; }
```

This works well except the last four items in the list will expand off the page. I wanted a way to make those items expand to the right and added this code

```
ul.menu ul ul {margin:0 0 0 10px; left:-13.4em; right:13em;  }
```

Which works perfectly except now they all go to the right. Im trying to find a way to set the first four items to the original css and the last four to the new css.

What I have tried so far

Test class in css

```
.test{margin:0 0 0 10px; left:12em;}


jQuery("ul.menu ul ul").children().filter(function (index, element) { return index <= 3; }).addClass("test");


var first_four = function(index, element){return index <= 3;};
jQuery("ul.menu").filter(first_four).children("ul").children("ul").addClass("test");

jQuery("ul.menu ul").filter(first_four).children("ul").addClass("test");
```

However these don't seem to work... Does jquery not like the ul.menu ul ul style? Can I get around that and still target those pieces?

Image of navigation https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChHGc.jpg

HTML code http://jsfiddle.net/Lzwkjc3m/

Comment: `nth-child` doesn't work? A JSfiddle would probably be helpful.

Comment: Yes if not you should at least add the HTML.

Comment: I'm not sure where to find the html because as I said its generated with aspx. Im going to add an image of what it actually looks like so everyone can see what im talking about.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there are just unordered lists adjacent to each other you can use the following to select the first four unordered lists (going on your question):

```
ul.menu ul ul {margin:0 0 0 10px; left:-13.4em; right:13em; }
ul.menu ul ul:nth-child(-n+4) {
   right: auto;
   left:12em;
}
```

If you're looking to select the first four unordered lists `nth-child` isn't supported by IE8 so instead you could use (the uglier):

```
ul.menu ul ul {margin:0 0 0 10px; left:-13.4em; right:13em; }
ul.menu ul ul:first-child,
ul.menu ul ul:first-child + ul,
ul.menu ul ul:first-child + ul + ul,
ul.menu ul ul:first-child + ul + ul + ul {
    right: auto;
    left:12em;
}
```

Comment: For this one the first way all of them seem to be following margin:0 0 0 10px; left:12em;
and then for the second one its reversed and they are all following margin:0 0 0 10px; left:-13.4em; right:13em;

Comment: @InFaF7 - I didn't add the first line as I thought that was implied.  Try now.

Comment: It was implied, but even after trying your updates im still getting the same return. The first example will set them all to the Right and the second example is setting them all to the Left. It's like it doesn't want to accept the selector

Comment: I need to see your html and then I can edit the answer.  Please edit your questions with some output.

Comment: okay im having trouble getting the html because its from a database and getting generated by aspx. The only thing I could think of would be to use the view source option from google chrome, would that help at all?

Comment: I added a chunk of the html code to the main question at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `nth-child` selector, which, among many implementations ([**See MDN docs here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)), can combined like this:

**Target the first four elements of a parent**

```
element:nth-child(-n + 4)
```

Or, perhaps:

**Target the fifth element and above**

```
element:nth-child(n + 5)
```

[**Sample working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5b60w0c9/)

**So...**

Then, in your case, maybe this would solve your problem:

```
ul.menu ul ul { margin:0 0 0 10px; left:12em; }
ul.menu ul ul:not(:nth-child(-n + 4)) {margin:0 0 0 10px; left:-13.4em; right:13em;  }
```

That would change the alignment to the right, except for the first four items...

Comment: It doesn't seem to be registering the second line of code, they are all accepting the first line. Am I missing something?

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm trying to work with a navigation that's generated through aspx and my menu's are looking more like this http://jsfiddle.net/5b60w0c9/2/ where the second and third levels need to be hit only

Comment: Then, perhaps you should be targeting to the `li` element, not the `ul`, like: `ul.menu ul ul li:not(:nth-child(-n + 4)) { ...`

Comment: I gave that a go and it still didn't split them nicely, it just messed up the way the menu's expanded on all of them... I wish this was in html it would be a lot easier